# Conditional Distribution of Order Statistics

Tags: order-statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with commom cdf F. Let $X_{(i)}$ be the ith order statistics of $X_i^,s$.Then prove that for $j>i, \{X_{(j)}|X_{(1)}=x_1,X_{(2)}=x_2,...,X_{(i)}=x_i\}$ and $\{X_{(j)}|X_{(i)}=x_i\}$ have same distibution. Anybody has any idea how to find the two conditional distributions?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The *conditioning* event is empty if $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_i)$ is not an increasing (not necessarily *strictly* increasing) sequence, while when the sequence has the desired property, we have that
$$A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \cdots \supset A_i$$ where
$A_k = \left(X_{(k)} = x_k\right), k = 1,2,\ldots i$. Can you figure out why? Then, the *conditioning* event, which is $A_1\cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_i$, telescopes very nicely.